# What is the WinRT analog to CreateFile's dwShareMode?

Tags: windows-runtime

In the Win32 CreateFile() API, I can specify dwShareMode when I open a file to prevent that file's being deleted or changed while I have it open.

I am looking for the C# analog in WinRT. Suppose I open a file:

```
StorageFile sf = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("x.txt");
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType iras = await sf.OpenReadAsync();
```

Then from an instance of CMD.EXE, I can CD to the ...\AppData\Local\Packages\zzz\LocalState directory and delete the file while the WinRT app has it open.

What can I do in my C# code to cause that deletion to fail?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly available.  This is typical for WinRT, it enforces apps to play nice and not hog resources at the api level by simply not exposing the capability.  It is also a rather severe usability problem, an app can get suspended for a very long time when the user switches away from it.  Keeping the file locked that long is of course very problematic, the user has no good way to diagnose the problem.

It is not an issue anyway when you use LocalFolder, nobody else can get to that.  Well, not counting somebody with a God account.

There is a backdoor available, you can pinvoke CreateFile2().  A version of CreateFile() that's allowed to be used by Store apps.  It has a dwShareMode argument.  Using it in a C# program is little fun and you'll have non-zero odds for a store validation rejection.

Comment: Well, if the file handle is being held open during the very long time (and it will be), I don't see why failing to expose locking is doing much to save resources. But I thank you for the response.

Comment: There's a world of difference between an opened file and a locked file.  It doesn't have anything to do with "saving resources", everything to do with usability.